# how to exchange selected item in a list box winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditem

i'm trying to change 'selectedItem' in the list box, but 'selectedItem' is staying as is even though i create a new item with different data. appreciate your help

```
this.listBox1.SelectedItem = new ListBoxItem(m_CurrentItem);

//next line operate the event list item changed
this.listBox1.Items[index] = this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: You could try selected index, like: `listBox1.SelectedIndex = integer here;`

Comment: use SelectedIndex: listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = m_CurrentItem

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing the operations in the reverse order ^^

You should first add the new item in the list box with

```
this.listBox1.Items.Add(YourNewItem);
```

Then you can select the newly inserted item with

```
this.listBox1.SelectedItem = YourNewItem;
```

Or, since the `.Add` Method adds the element in the last position of the `Items` array, you can use

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = this.listBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

See this article for reference on the `ListBox.SelectedItem` Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx
:)